# SCNNode Disobeying Position after Placement

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I'm using Apples SceneKit and have a custom `.dae` asset. I've converted the asset to a `.scn` file. I am grabbing the `SCNNode` by name from the `.scn` file. After placing the SCNNode in my SCNView scene as a child node and setting it's position to be `SCNVector3(0,0,-1)`, it ignores this position and instead follows my phone location. The asset renders right on top of me and when I walk away, it follows me. It's getting to be very annoying and I can't find a solution.

However, if I replace the SCNNode taken from the `.scn` file, and use a SCNBox, instead, everything works just fine. The cube stays in it's set position.

Here is the relevant code:

```
func addCoins(at position: SCNVector3) {

    let donorScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/nodes.scn")
    if let coin = donorScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "coin", recursively: true) {
        coin.position = position // 0, 0, -1 (right in front of me)
        scene.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(coin)
    }
}
```

Attached is a screenshot showing what I see whenever I move.

[image: SCNNode]

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my 3d asset was too large. The asset was created at 200cm^2 which is 2meter^2 in the 3d modeling program. After the asset was imported into Xcode, it's interpreted by SceneKit as 200meters, which is way too large for SceneKit, apparently.